# Iterate over JSON formatted array of objects and modify and extend it, preferably using Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, iterator, underscore.js

I have data retrieved from a database in JSON format that gets assigned to a variable - 'var tabs'.

The formatted JSON is as follows:

```
[{
    "TAB_ID": "1",
    "TAB_NAME": "TAB ONE",
    "TAB_DISPLAY": "1",
    "QUESTIONS": [{
        "QUESTION_ID": 1,
        "QUESTION": "Question number one",
        "ANSWER": ""
    }, {
        "QUESTION_ID": 2,
        "QUESTION": "Question number two",
        "ANSWER": ""
    }, {
        "QUESTION_ID": 3,
        "QUESTION": "Question number six",
        "ANSWER": ""
    }]
}, {
    "TAB_ID": "1",
    "TAB_NAME": "TAB ONE",
    "TAB_DISPLAY": "1",
    "QUESTIONS": [{
        "QUESTION_ID": 1,
        "QUESTION": "Question number one",
        "ANSWER": "Some Other Answer"
    }, {
        "QUESTION_ID": 2,
        "QUESTION": "Question number two",
        "ANSWER": ""
    }, {
        "QUESTION_ID": 3,
        "QUESTION": "Question number six",
        "ANSWER": "Some Still Different Answer"
    }]
}]
```

I need to iterate over the array and do the following:

For each QUESTION in the TAB, if the QUESTION has an ANSWER, I need to add an additional key/value of "HAS_ANSWER": "1" to the QUESTION.

```
    {
        "QUESTION_ID": 1,
        "QUESTION": "Question number one",
        "ANSWER": "Some Other Answer",
        "HAS_ANSWER": "1"
    }
```

I've spent hours reading posts, viewing sample code and reading the Underscore documentation, and I know this should be fairly simple, but I can't wrap my head around how to approach this.

My understanding is that I probably want to use nested _.map functions, but all of the examples I've looked at return a subset of the array of objects, not a modified and extended one, and I need to end up with exactly the same formatted JSON data (array of objects), but with the changes and additions noted above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

Using this:

```
data = _.map(data, obj => _.map(obj.QUESTIONS, q => {
    if (q.ANSWER) {
        q.HAS_ANSWER = 1;
    }
    return q;
}));
```

This iterates over the questions, and modifies them accordingly, but the returned object drops the outer layer of data - it just returns an array of questions, and doesn't retain the TAB data:

```
    "TAB_ID": "1",
    "TAB_NAME": "TAB ONE",
    "TAB_DISPLAY": "1",
```

The solution is to use _.each on the outer array, and _.map on the inner array.

```
data = _.each(data, obj => _.map(obj.QUESTIONS, q => {
    if (q.ANSWER) {
        q.HAS_ANSWER = 1;
    }
    return q;
}));
```

Note: This => syntax only works in the newer implementations of Javascript, and isn't currently supported in Safari / Webkit, so use this syntax instead for better compatibility

```
data = _.each(data, function(obj){
    _.map(obj.QUESTIONS, function(q){
       if (q.ANSWER) {
           q.HAS_ANSWER = 1;
       }
       return q;
    });
});
```

This handles things exactly the way I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using plain JavaScript, using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
// Iterate over data
data = data.map(obj => obj.QUESTIONS.map(q => {
    // If question has answer, then add `HAS_ANSWER` property
    if (q.ANSWER) {
        q.HAS_ANSWER = 1;
    }

    // Update question object
    return q;
}));
```

```js
var data = [{
    "TAB_ID": "1",
    "TAB_NAME": "TAB ONE",
    "TAB_DISPLAY": "1",
    "QUESTIONS": [{
        "QUESTION_ID": 1,
        "QUESTION": "Question number one",
        "ANSWER": ""
    }, {
        "QUESTION_ID": 2,
        "QUESTION": "Question number two",
        "ANSWER": ""
    }, {
        "QUESTION_ID": 3,
        "QUESTION": "Question number six",
        "ANSWER": ""
    }]
}, {
    "TAB_ID": "1",
    "TAB_NAME": "TAB ONE",
    "TAB_DISPLAY": "1",
    "QUESTIONS": [{
        "QUESTION_ID": 1,
        "QUESTION": "Question number one",
        "ANSWER": "Some Other Answer"
    }, {
        "QUESTION_ID": 2,
        "QUESTION": "Question number two",
        "ANSWER": ""
    }, {
        "QUESTION_ID": 3,
        "QUESTION": "Question number six",
        "ANSWER": "Some Still Different Answer"
    }]
}];

data = data.map(obj => obj.QUESTIONS.map(q => {
    if (q.ANSWER) {
        q.HAS_ANSWER = 1;
    }
    return q;
}));

console.log(data);
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

---

Same code in Underscore/Lodash

```
data = _.map(data, obj => _.map(obj.QUESTIONS, q => {
    if (q.ANSWER) {
        q.HAS_ANSWER = 1;
    }
    return q;
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using standard Javascript's [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method, it could look something like this:

```
tabs.forEach(tab => {
  tab['QUESTIONS'].forEach(question => {
    if (question['ANSWER']) {
      question['HAS_ANSWER'] = 1;
    }
  });
});
```

```js
var tabs = [{
    "TAB_ID": "1",
    "TAB_NAME": "TAB ONE",
    "TAB_DISPLAY": "1",
    "QUESTIONS": [{
        "QUESTION_ID": 1,
        "QUESTION": "Question number one",
        "ANSWER": ""
    }, {
        "QUESTION_ID": 2,
        "QUESTION": "Question number two",
        "ANSWER": ""
    }, {
        "QUESTION_ID": 3,
        "QUESTION": "Question number six",
        "ANSWER": ""
    }]
}, {
    "TAB_ID": "1",
    "TAB_NAME": "TAB ONE",
    "TAB_DISPLAY": "1",
    "QUESTIONS": [{
        "QUESTION_ID": 1,
        "QUESTION": "Question number one",
        "ANSWER": "Some Other Answer"
    }, {
        "QUESTION_ID": 2,
        "QUESTION": "Question number two",
        "ANSWER": ""
    }, {
        "QUESTION_ID": 3,
        "QUESTION": "Question number six",
        "ANSWER": "Some Still Different Answer"
    }]
}];

tabs.forEach(tab => {
  tab['QUESTIONS'].forEach(question => {
    if (question['ANSWER']) {
      question['HAS_ANSWER'] = 1;
    }
  });
});

console.log(tabs);
```

This approach modifies the data in place.